# Friendly_id should generate same slug for inherited STI table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-url, friendly-id

Friendly_id should generate same slug for inherited STI table.

I have a report model and a demo_report model which is inherited from report model, first a slug is generated for report using friendly_id. This is good
e.g. `test-report`

But when same slug I want to  generate for demo_report model it doesn't accept same slug like `test-report` , it adds some random_id 
e.g. `test-report-4jfjfj4-4ufjks-787dns`

I want to achieve

`localhost:3000/reports/test-report`

`localhost:3000/demo-reports/test-report`

Is it possible?, any help on this please

Comment: do you add friendly id config in demo report model?

Comment: I have defined `friendly_id.rb` in `config/initializers` and extended `extend friendly_id` in report and demo-report both the models. what config you are talking about?

Comment: sorry, I means `extend friendly_id`. Do you add unique index to slug column of table? If so, I  think it's not possible to have same slug.